# Do all isometries of the Euclidean space necessarily send shapes to congruent shapes?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, lie-groups, quaternions

> Proposition: $\mathbb{S^3}$ can be decomposed into disjoint congruent circles
>
> Solution:The quaternions of unit length $q=(a,b,c,d)$ of unit length satisfy the equation
> $$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 =1$$
>
> The unit quaternions also form a group under quaternion multiplication. One subgroup of this group is $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ which is a circle in the plane spanned by $1$ and $i$. It follows that any coset $qH$ is also a unit circle, because multiplication by quaternion of unit length is an isometry. Since the cosets $qH$ fill the whole group and are disjoint, we have a decomposition of the $3-$ sphere into unit circles
>
> John Stillwell's book: Naive Lie theory

The point that I don't get in the above proof is how it was taken that $qH$ is a unit circle. I understand multiplication by quaternions preserves distance between points, but how it is that just preserving length and origin is enough to know that circles will get sent to circles?

Comment: also sends the 2-plane spanned by $1,i$   to another 2-plane that passes through the origin

Comment: An alternative approach: every isometry is affine, and by the isometry condition the singular values of the linear part are all $1$. Thus by singular value decomposition, the isometry is essentially two rotations, followed by a translation, which evidently sends shapes to congruent copies.

Comment: Could you please write a detailed answer based on this idea? Seems very interesting to me @William

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, every isometry is a congruence map (and vice versa).

Clearly, the composition of isometrics is an isometry, and the composition of congruence maps is a congruence map. Also, the reflection at a plane in 3space is clearly both an isometry and a congruence map.

Let $f$ be any isometry of 3space. Pick a point $A$ and let $r_1$ be the reflection at the plane that perpendicularly bisects the line segment $Af(A)$ (or let $r_1$ be the identity map if $f(A)=A$). Note that said plane is also precisely the locus of all points having same distance from $A$ and $f(A)$. Then $r_1\circ A$ is an isometry with fix point $A$. Next pick $B\ne A$ and define $r_2$ analogously such that $r_2\circ r_1\circ f$ fixes $B$. As $A$ has same distance from $B$ and $r_1(f(B))$, it is on the picked reflection plane and hence $A$ is also a fix point of $r_2\circ r_1\circ f$. The points on line $AB$ can be characterised by distances alone, namely as points $X$ with $d(X,A)+d(X,B)=d(A,B)$ or $|d(X,A)-d(X,B)|=d(A,B)$. Therefore, all points on this line are fix points. Pick $C$ not on the line and repeat the procedure. We obtain an isometry $r_3\circ r_2\circ r_1\circ f$ that fixes $A,B,C$ (and I fact the plane defined by these points). Repeat a last time with a fourth point $D$ not in the plane $ABC$ to obtain an isometry $r_4\circ r_3 \circ r_2 \circ r_1\circ f$ that fixes $A,B,C,D$. Any other point is uniquely determined by its distances to these four points, hence must Ali be fixed by this isometry. We conclude that our composed isometry is the identity, or equivalently, $f=r_1\circ r_2\circ r_3\circ r_4$, which is a congruence map.

Comment: How does $r_1 \circ A$ fix A? It sends $ A \to f(A)$ to my understnading

Comment: Who is ali O_O?

Comment: Could you please clarify the choice of $B$ a bite more? It is unclear to me. Also at end why does four points uniquely identify a specific isometry

Comment: The OP is working in 4-dimensional space, so a few modifications may be due :-)